# Looking for a spike

Tags: part-identification

I spend some hours looking for the part attached to the microfigure of this picture:

[image]

Can anyone identify the spike attached to the head of the microfig.

Comment: That does not look like legit LEGO, it looks like a knock off brand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Both the gun in the minifigure’s hand as well as the “spike” on the microfig’s head are not LEGO pieces, but third party accessories from [BrickArms](https://brickarms.com).

The “spike” is [this bayonet piece](http://brickarms.com/Bayonet.php), and the gun is most likely [this piece](http://brickarms.com/Sawed-Off-Shotgun.php).

The bayonet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!!! i really appreciate it :) Do you know where to find the torso and this head with the bloody scars?